# My recursive function isnt in infinite loop. Why?

Tags: javascript, recursion, nightmare

The nightmare is working, of course I'm testing this tool but nway, the mainly problem is why my function isnt on a infinite loop? Since i didnt make a condition to page. May I'm doing this wrong?

The case that I wanted was: whenever page loaded, I get the tittle with page then call the function again to next page till the last page.

I tried without success the setTimeout too.

My console log just print 1 then finish.

The code snippet is here:-

```
var pagn = 1;
function ab(page){
    nightmare.goto(url_base+"&page="+page)
             .evaluate(() => {
                return document.title;
            })
            .end()
            .then((title) => {
                console.log(title + ":" + page);
                ab(++pagn);
                //setTimeout("page(" + page + ")", 5000);
            }).catch(()=>{console.log("Error");});
}
ab(pagn);
```

Comment: try changing ab(page++); to ab(++page);

Comment: didnt worked, still the same.

Comment: What if there is a reject thrown by nightmare.goto(). We didn't write any catch.

Comment: A global variable named page and an argument named page, the question begs, if you want to know the page count in the end? Neither ab, nor the callback then returns anything, do you want to wait for it to complete?

Comment: @Atiq I added .catch(()=>{console.log("error");}); but still printing only tittle:1

Comment: @Icepickle I dont want to know the count yet, the function was supposed to run at least infinite times. xD this is the problem, its just running once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are ending your [nightmare](/questions/tagged/nightmare) session with the `.end()` statement, which stops the nightmare engine, and so node exits after running through the remaining `.then` statements.

To test your code, I rewrote your function a bit, so that it scrapes a particular website, and exits when it finds the same page multiple times (which is kinda my test scenario, so you might have to adapt it for your code)

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

function scrapePages( targetUrl, curPage = 0, transform = (url, page) => `${url}?page=${page}`, pageSet = new Set() ) {
    console.info('Trying to scrape page ' + transform( targetUrl, curPage ) );
    return nightmare
        .goto( transform( targetUrl, curPage ) )
        .evaluate( () => document.title )
        .then( (title) => {
            if (pageSet.has( title )) {
            throw 'page already exists';
            }
            pageSet.add( title );
            console.info( title + ':' + curPage );
            return scrapePages( targetUrl, curPage + 1, transform, pageSet );
        })
        .catch( ( err ) => {
            console.error( err );
            return { maxPages: curPage, pages: pageSet };
        } );
}

scrapePages( 'some-paged-url', 0, (url, page) => url + '/' + (page + 1) )
    .then( ({ maxPages, pages }) => {
        // end nightmare process
        nightmare.end().then( () => {
            console.info(`Found ${maxPages} pages`);
        });
    } )
    .catch( err => console.error('Error occured', err ) );
```

The biggest difference, as you can see, is that the ending of the nightmare process only occurs once the scraping ran through. At that time, you would have the total pages available and all pages that were called successfully

Comment: HF. You saved my life, i didnt get it the .end() was finishing the nightmare. oops, I need to read all the docs again, but I think the nightmare docs arent updated but thanks again m8.

Answer (score 0):

What if there is a reject thrown by nightmare.goto(). You should implement catch()
`page++` didn't pass the incremented value as its post increment operator. `page + 1` or `++page` should do the tricks.

```
var page = 1;
function ab(page){
    nightmare.goto(url_base+"&page="+page)
            .evaluate(() => {
                return document.title;
                    })
            .end()
            .then((title) => {
                console.log(title + ":" + page);
                ab(page+1);
                //setTimeout("page(" + page + ")", 5000);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Search failed:', error)
                ab(page);
            }); 
    }

ab(page);
```

Comment: `ab(page++)` is not a good idea, it should preferably be `ab(page+1)` (as it is the argument variable, not the global var). Now you will probably have a lot of errors in case something doesn't exist, it will indeed continue to retry, but from what the OP wrote, I think the error would only come on the last page

Comment: @Icepickle this problem can be surrounded by just changing the name of global property or param. But still the same problem, just working once.

Comment: @Icepickle I agree. page++ wont pass the updated value as its post increment.  page+1 or ++page should work

Answer (score 0):

you should not pass the page variable when defining a global variable else it will be overwritten everytime..

```
var page = 1;
function ab(){
    nightmare.goto(url_base+"&page="+page)
         .evaluate(() => {
            return document.title;
        })
        .end()
        .then((title) => {
            console.log(title + ":" + page);
            ab(page++);
            //setTimeout("page(" + page + ")", 5000);
        }); 
}

ab();
```